# How to open a dialog when clicking a card but prevent opening the dialog when clicking child elements?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using the latest Version of Vuetify and want to open a dialog when I click on a card. The problem is that this card contains multiple child elements ( e.g. a form ) and I only want to open a dialog when the card itself had been clicked.

[Reproduction link](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-dialog v-model="isDialogOpen">
        <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
          <!-- <v-btn v-bind="props">Open Dialog</v-btn> -->
          <v-card v-bind="props">
            <v-card-title>If (only) card was clicked it should open a dialog</v-card-title>
            <v-card-text>
              <v-form>
                <v-text-field label="This is just" />
                <v-text-field label="a very basic form" />
                <v-text-field label="inside a card" />
              </v-form>
            </v-card-text>
            <v-card-actions>
              <v-btn>Some action</v-btn>
              <v-spacer />
              <v-btn>Other action</v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-card>
        </template>
        <v-card>Dialog goes here</v-card>
      </v-dialog>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'
  
const isDialogOpen = ref(false)
</script>
```

The dialog opens when clicking on the card but it also opens when clicking something inside the card, e.g. the text fields or the buttons.

Is there a way to only open the dialog when clicking the card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place `@click.stop` on the elements on which you don't want the click to bubble.

[Working demo](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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).

Documentation: [event modifiers](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#event-modifiers).

---

Note: if you place `@click.stop` on the card's immediate children (which is what you asked for), you won't be able to open the dialogue anymore as the entire surface of the card is covered by: `<v-card-title />`, `<v-card-text />` and `<v-card-actions />`, effectively leaving no pixel where a click would actually open the dialogue.